# looking for BKZ earliest algorithm and its application in cryptography

Tags: reference-request

I am reading lattice based cryptography for my master thesis,
I am looking for the earliest version of BKZ algorithm, and its applications in cryptography, to understand it very well, I already know about LLL algorithm.
and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BKZ was described in *Lattice basis reduction: improved practical algorithms and solving subset sum problems* by  C. P. Schnorr, M. Euchner in 1994. As the title suggests, it was first used for solving the subset sum problem.

<s>https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/2126483728</s>

Updated the link(s) because Microsoft Academics is closing.

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Lattice-basis-reduction%3A-Improved-practical-and-sum-Schnorr-Euchner/ca9742f2d1bca725a1a66164e036ad6378c5625b

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Lattice-Basis-Reduction%3A-Improved-Practical-and-Sum-Schnorr-Euchner/f6659bfc4ff29a107e8dfd612099f4f8d918fe79

Comment: does there any earlier courses i want to understand it very well thanks in advance, i saw the article...

Comment: @NdrXbrain I don't think such course exists, because it'll have too low a view count for Youtubers to be willing to make.

Comment: what about lecture 
thanks Sir Danny

Comment: @NdrXbrain That'll be beyond my realm of knowledge, but searching for keywords such as linear algebra, lattice, etc. may help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The Schnorr-Euchner practical BKZ implementation was preceded by a [1987 theory paper](https://core.ac.uk/display/82789767), that paper also references [prior work by Kannan](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800061.808749)

Comment: Thanks dear Daniel

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can generally find slightly-less-formal descriptions that can be easier than papers, for example [Michael Walter](https://blog.simons.berkeley.edu/author/michael-walter/) has some blog posts, or even [his thesis](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/5n51z56s).